# Why doesn't eclipse complain about this deprecated method?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-lint

In my manifest.xml I have defined:

```
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion:"8" android:targetSdkVersion:"8" />
```

and in android's documentation for View class it's been said:

```
    setBackground(Drawable) 
    // ADDED IN API LEVEL 16
```

This method has been added in api level 16. But when I use it in my code, eclipse doesn't issue any complaint and my app crashes on devices running api under 16.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Do you have android Lint enabled for your project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you probably target Version 8 but compile with 19.

Comment: What do you mean? I compile with 19? what does this mean ?

Comment: when you created the project you had three options to set,
`min sdk`, `target sdk` and `compile with`
you usually set the min-sdk to something around your value, depending on your application. the target-sdk depends on your application too, but the sdk you compile with is new latest one.

Comment: Mine (sdk version) is 17 actually. What should I do now?

Answer (score 2):

You could configure your project's Android Lint preferences like this:

1. go to project --> properties --> Android Lint Preferences
2. Set `NewApi` to severity `error`
3. Click <kbd>Apply</kbd> button

[image]

---

then it should underline the setBackground method red and mark it as an error. That works for me in my project.

Answer (score 0):

You are compiling against a version higher than 16. Go to your `project.properties` file at the root of your project and change the line `target=android-someNumber` to `target=android-8`.